# How can I dynamically generate javascript within a script tag using jade and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, d3.js, pug

I am trying to dynamically generate json data for a d3 graph. I am not sure if this is the optimal strategy, but my attempt is essentially to have the d3 code within a script tag, and then have the json be generated via an object passed in express.

The issue I have is that I am unsure how to dynamically generate the json data within the script tag. If there is a better code design strategy for dynamically generating json objects to pass to d3 to generate charts using jade/pug please let me know. The code below doesn't work.

Code below:

**jade code**

```
 //...content above, d3 to draw the graph below

        svg(height="800", width="1000").graph        
        script.
          var svg = d3.select("svg"),
          var data = #{dataObj}; // <--? how do I pass the json data object passed via route.js within the script tag?
```

...

**route.js**

```
let dataObj = {
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "Fantine", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Blacheville", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Favourite", "group": 3},
    {"id": "test", "group": 3},
    ],
    "links": [
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "test", "value": 4},
    ]
  };
    res.render('drawGraph', { dataObj});
```

**console**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
var data = [object Object];
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Stretch0 mentioned you are missing the key to the object

```
res.render('drawGraph', { dataObj: dataObj});
```

But this alone wont solve the problem. You will have to use JSON.stringify in the pug template to display the object

from

```
 var data = #{dataObj};
```

to

```
var data = !{JSON.stringify(dataObj)};
```

`#{} escapes characters, so inorder to avoid escaping you can use !{}

Comment: Thanks for the JSON.stringify answer. Please note in the express version I am using (latest), you do not need to use dataObj: dataObj. As they are the same name I can use dataObj alone and it passes. If I wanted to use a different name then yes I would need to do something like myDataObj:dataObj, or dataObj:{key:value}. If I pass in an object previously declared it's been working fine as posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an object into an object without a key.

Try `res.render('drawGraph', { dataObj: dataObj});`